# My Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't update anymore

Tags: 14.04

I have recently noticed that I can't install new versions. For example I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

I get message that I have the newest version. But my version is 42! How to fix it?

Comment: First thought, change your download server in Settings -> Software & Updates then the 'download from' dropdown. Try the main server.

Comment: @Parto Thank you for your help. I followed your andvice + I checked all updates on update tab. Now everything is ok.

Comment: Cool. Let me put it in as an answer so that we can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change your update settings, follow these steps:

1. Change the 'download from' server by going to `Settings -> Software & Updates`.

[image: System Settings Window]

2. Then in the `Ubuntu Software` tab, select a different server or select the main server.

[image]

3. You can also check the updates settings that you want in the `updates` tab.

[image]

4. Run these commands to install any available updates:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```